# site status: Closed_beta

Tags: discussion

Will stackauth ever show a site as closed_beta? Is there much point if it's closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closed_beta` in the API is equivalent to Private Beta in Area51.

"Closed" as in "to the public" not as in "shutdown."  Sites that are shutdown cease to exist in the API.

Comment: Yes I know but who can use a site during private beta?

Comment: @Jonathan - anyone who committed to the Area51 proposal.  The API will allow anyone to read the site if they wish.

Answer (score 0):

> Will stackauth ever show a site as closed_beta?

private beta data is available via API, the last time I checked.

> Is there much point if it's closed?

depends on whether that data is of value to you.